# Frequently getting "ModuleNotFoundError" while importing packages to python code

Tags: python, flask

I am fairly new to python and have been frequently hitting problems similar to the above where I get the `ModuleNotFoundError` when using `import`.

This time around it is with flask.

I have seen similar questions and most of them recommend running `impost sys print(sys.path)` in order to check if the paths are all right. I did run and checked that I can find flask inside site-packages under \Python39\lib

I have also checked `PYTHONPATH[0]` and it is empty as it should, to be filled with my code.py file directory.

Also made sure it is correctly installed by re-running `pip install flask` only to get a number of "requirement satisfied" messages.

Can someone guide me to some sort of tutorial on the topic? I am sort of in the doll drums here with my learning getting repeatedly locked because of this!

Another "element" -- the issue seems to be related to my specific installation for Visual Code / Python. I have another machine where I have VS Code/python installed where the code worked just fine, no error. What should I uninstall / install from scratch to make this thing go away? I've seen posts where ppl talk about similar issues having to do with fact of having multiple Python versions installed on the machine. This is not my case -- I have checked both machines and all I have is Python 3.9

I happen to have "Mu" installed to teach code to my kids. Running the script in Mu works just fine, no errors... I have uninstalled / re-installed VS Code and it did not help!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("Home.html")

@app.route('/about/')
def about():
    return render_template("About.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\python_basics\WebPage\script2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import render_template
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Comment: Can you post full traceback you receive? It's hard to find cause without seeing it.

Comment: Edited above to include both code and traceback

Comment: You'r code looks fine so there must be a problem with configuration. Are you running your script from command line or via VS Code? You might have multiple Python's version installed. The easiest way to check installed modules for Python is to run `python -m pip freeze` command
If you use VS Code check if you are using correct interpreter - Ctrl+Shift+P and type Python: Select Interpreter- check if path points to correct version of Python.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Did all of that. Made sure I have just one version running, no virtual environments as well (actually just today got to knowing what one was and how to fire it up! hehehe). Agree it has to do with my install. I actually uninstalled VS Code, python, reinstalled it all and now it works fine. On your question I was running via VS Code "Play/run" button, which I understand then runs it via command line. Anyway... things working now!